# Environment variables not converted to system properties

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables, system-properties

Working on a legacy Spring based application (Spring 4.3), I have a strange behavior: environment variables are not resolved by Spring.
For example I have this environment variable: `HOST_SERVICE_BASE_URL`, when I refer to it in the application with `${host.service.base.url}` the property is not resolved and the application fails during start up.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'host.service.base.url' in value "${host.service.base.url}
```

I defined these beans for property resolution:

```
    @Bean
    public PropertiesFactoryBean applicationProperties( ResourceLoader resourceLoader ) {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactory = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactory.setLocations( resourceLoader.getResource( "/WEB-INF/config/application.properties" ),
                    resourceLoader.getResource( "/WEB-INF/config/application-dev.properties" ) );
        return propertiesFactory;
    }
```

And

```
    <bean id="dataConfigPropertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
        <property name="searchSystemEnvironment" value="true"/>
        <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
        <property name="properties" ref="applicationProperties"/>
    </bean>
```

Comment: Environment variables will never the converted to system properties. Do you really have an environment variable OR do you have a System Property (passed with `-D`). Also why the mix of XML and Java Config and do you by anychange have multiple `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` instances AND are you loading multiple configs?

Comment: @M.Deinum  I have environnement variables not system properties. The mix with xml is because it's a legacy application and I don't want to migrate all configurations

Comment: Ah already see your issue. You should be using a `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` not a `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` and loading the properties, unless you need them, should be done using the same class.

Comment: And yes there are multiple configs loaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the (now deprecated) `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` while that can consult the system environment it lacks the feature of mapping those properties to values. I.e `HOST_SERVICE_BASE_URL` isn't mapped as `host.service.base.url`.

That support is only available in the `SystemEnvironmentPropertySource` which is automatically registered and consulted when using the `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` (recommended as of Spring 5.2, but available since 3.1).

```xml
<bean id="dataConfigPropertyConfigurer"
          class="org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="properties" ref="applicationProperties"/>
</bean>
```

Or in Java to replace the `applicationProperties` bean and XML portion.

```java
@Bean
public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer placeholderConfigurer() {
  PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer configurer = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  configurer.setLocations({"/WEB-INF/config/application.properties", /WEB-INF/config/application-dev.properties"});
  configurer.setIgnoreResourceNotFound(true);
  return configurer;
}
```

Or if you really stick with XML use the `<context:property-placeholder />` tag, which automatically does this.

```xml
<context:property-placeholder properties="applicationProperties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```

or

```xml
<context:property-placeholder locations="/WEB-INF/config/application.properties,/WEB-INF/config/application-dev.properties" ignore-resource-not-found="true" />
```